# Preallocation of array sizes in Modelica mos script

Tags: arrays, modelica, dymola, openmodelica, pre-allocation

I am writing a **mos** script in Dymola in which I am dynamically computing array elements inside *for* loops. A lot of information gets printed on the command window. every time it prints

```
Redeclaring variable: Real traj_phie [34, 1002];
Redeclaring variable: Real traj_phie [35, 1002];
```

etc. I don't want to "**redeclare**" my array every time, I just want to "**fill**" it. Will the Preallocation of the array size solve this problem? If so, how can I preallocate array in mos script? I tried different ways like

```
Real[50,1002] traj_phie;
```

for which Dymola throws an error. So my questions are
1) Array preallocation inside mos script
2) Suppressing the command output.
Can someone help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an advanced flag, which allows you to suppress the command output:

```
Advanced.EchoScriptCommands = false
```

To initialize a vector, matrix or array with a certain size use the fill() function.
There is nothing like NaN in Modelica, so you have to initialize with a certain value.

Then you can use slicing operations to assign just the line / row / elements of interest.

```
traj_phie = fill(0.0, 50, 10);

// Assign line by-line
for i in 1:50 loop
  traj_phie[i, :] = i*ones(10);
end for;
```

Comment: As a slight variation you can use fill(0.0, 50, 10) instead of fill(0, 50, 10) to ensure that traj_phie is seen as a real variable (although it shouldn't matter).